# How do I do a timetostring for this Variable. Is it possible?

Tags: php, strtotime

just wondering if someone can help me out with this. Is there a way to do a proper strtotime with this variable?

```
$var = "Thursday October 26 2012 12:59:59 PM";
```

When I do a `strtotime`, it appears as 1351789199. But when I change the var to this:

```
$var = "Thursday October 26 2012 12:59:50 PM";
```

It still shows the same `strtotime` as 1351789199.

Any thoughts? The $var is stored in the database so I cannot change it unless I use another function to make it look different.

Thanks in advance experts!

Comment: what else would you expect it to do?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Can you show your code? I would think that you missed an assignment for $var. It should be different if you adjust the seconds like that.

Comment: Are you sure the value of `$var`?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem right. I get different times. Keep in mind my time zone is different but at least the values are slightly different.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$time = time();

$var = "Thursday October 26 2012 12:59:59 PM";

echo strtotime($var, $time).PHP_EOL;

$var = "Thursday October 26 2012 12:59:50 PM";

echo strtotime($var, $time).PHP_EOL;

?>
```

### outputs

```
1351799999
1351799990
```

Answer (score 0):

SUPER weird, but for some reason, Chrome seemed have cached the info? I didn't think you could cache time, but it worked fine in Firefox. Thanks all for your quick replies.